Replacing elements in a numpy array by arrays of different sizes
I need to loop over the entries of an array and replace each entry with all the entries another array (the number of elements that I will be adding is a function of the entry of the original array, so the length of the resulting array is a priori unknown). I am struggling with the creation of the new array. For example, if
import numpy as np

a = np.array([ [1, 4],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 4],
       [2, 5]] )

b= np.array([[10, 40],
       [2, 3],
        [1,1]] )
c= np.array([[20, 40] ])
d = np.array([])
e= np.array([])

I would like that the entries of b replace [1, 4], the entries of c replace [2, 3] and so on. In this case, I would obtain
[[10 40]
 [ 2  3]
 [ 1  1]
 [20 40]]

What I had in mind but I am not able to do it is no create an empty array and then do a for loop on the elements of a and for each element of a append to the empty array the array that I want:
empt = np.array([]) #I don't now how large this array is until I do all the replacements.
for row in a:
   np.append( ) #here I would like to append to the empty array f(row), where in the above example f([1, 4]) = b, f([2, 3]) = c,  f([2, 4]) = d and f([2, 5]) = e.

I would know how to do this in Python using lists but I don't know how to do it in Numpy with arrays.
Edit: In Python I would have done something like this using lists: although here I still get the output [[1, 1], [1, 1], [4, 4]] instead of [([1, 1], [1, 1]), [4, 4], []],
def funct(n):
    if n ==[1,1]:
        return [1,1], [1,1]
    if n == [2,2]:
        return [4,4]
    else:
        return []

a = [[1,1] ,[2,2], [3,3] ]

l = []
for element in a:
    l.append(funct(element))



I don't understand the reasoning behind the replacements. Maybe it would be clearer if you show how would you do it with lists.

Something like this --although the final output has to be [[1, 1], [1, 1], [4, 4]] instead of [([1, 1], [1, 1]), [4, 4], []]                                                                           ```def funct(n):
if n ==[1,1]:
return [1,1], [1,1]
if n == [2,2]:
return [4,4]
else:
return []
a = [[1,1] ,[2,2], [3,3] ]
l = []
for element in a:
l.append(funct(element)) ```

Please edit your post to include additional code. It's completely unreadable as comment text.

sounds like this is best done with lists.  To be clear show the list code, and we can suggest any improvements.  keep in mind that np.append is not a list clone.  And np.array([]) is not a [] clone.

x[indx] = y works if the lhs and rhs have the right shapes.  Broadcasting is import concept for this.  y of varioius  size can fit in x[indx], but you can't put something larger in x.  In general you cannot increase the size of an array by assignment.   Pay close attention to dimensions.

since you are replacing everything in a, just create a new array ie np.r_[b,c] or just np.row_stack([b, c])
